# stay compatible past 2038

Tags: time, posix, long-integer, year2038

I'm writing a piece of code that I want to work even past 2038. I need to store an epoch timestamp in a map and was wondering if I am compatible going forward when I use a `long long` instead of an `int` to store `tiume(NULL)` or how else I best go about this? I'm aware that even using an `unsigned int` would give nme plenty of more room - but is that or `long long` the best way to go about it?

Comment: I checked this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem, it will be a problem for 32-bit Linux/OS with 32-bit time_t, not for 64 bit linux/OS with 64-bit time_t.

Comment: do you also expect 32 bit systems to be around after 2038?

Comment: @Arno for sure they'll still be around! Consider that today, there are still  a lot of 8bit systems around, too. Think embedded devices (not PCs)! Hence, `long long` will be 64 bit on either, 32 or 64bit systems...

Comment: @dkb yes, but the application needs to be written accordingly, too. `long long` will give me 64bit in any case.